# Getting fewer/matching objects from json file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, get

My json file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "type" : "hardware"
    },
    {
        "id" : "2",
        "type" : "software"
    }
]
```

Now when I run following code :

```
$http({
        method: 'get',
        url: '/tools.json'
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        ///whatever
    })
```

I get these two objects for rederning via `ng-repeat`, that's fine.

Now, I want to create filters in my app, like display only "Hardware" or "Software", for this, which is the best way to achieve this, is there a way where I can just get Hardware typed objects from JSON itself? (querying JSON and get matching objects) and how can I do that? What should I change in code in-order to do this or should I use Angular filters to render Hardware types after getting entire JSON.

I don't have much experience in Angular, let me know if there is any other way I can achieve what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's your choice completely.

Ideally, your backend should be returning the JSON filtered by the query.

If you want instant-responsiveness, you may use Angularjs's filters to do the filtering for you on the same data which you'd fetch once from the server. This also has an added benefit of doing full-text search, which is really neat.

Comment: Thanks Harsh, can you help me with what should I change in my code in-order to receive ONLY matching objects?

Comment: What does /tools.json have? Does is directly read a file and return it?

Comment: Since you have not shown any code about the server, I can't make any assumption about it. Show us the server code if you want to **receieve only matching objects from the server**.

Comment: Use Robby's method then, or use the Lodash library's [Filter](http://lodash.com/docs#filter) function.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to filter the JSON data, you could use the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method as follows:

```
var hardware = data.reduce(function(result, current) {
    if(current.type === 'hardware') {
        result.push(current);
    }

    return result;
}, []);
```

Fiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kthPL/).

Comment: Thanks Robby, `reduce` is cool. But, is it possible to get just "Hardware" typed objects returned while GET request to JSON file?

Comment: @MaulikSuchak If it's just a plain file you're getting: no, I don't think so. If you're dealing with huge amounts of data, and don't want to keep everything in memory, you could look into JSON streaming and weed out the non-hardware entries as they're being streamed in.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal place for this filtering would be on backend, given the type. But for some reason, if you want to do this on browser, you can use a simple for loop to filter objects with type hardware. A cleaner way of doing this would be with underscore. Include underscore source file in your project and do _.filter function to filter the objects you want. You can read more about filter function here: http://underscorejs.org/#filter